# How to toggle the visibility of 1 or multiple activities in Kotlin

Tags: android, android-activity, kotlin

The problem at hand is pretty straight forward I just have a button that generates and displays a number 1-9.  This consists of a button, a seek bar and a text view.

I'd like to hide these activities once a 9 is rolled, but I'm not sure how to toggle the visibility of the button, seek bar and text view.

```
    val rollButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.rollButton)
    val resultsTextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.resultsTextView)
    val seekBar = findViewById<SeekBar>(R.id.seekBar)

    seekBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)
    rollButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)
    resultsTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)
```

```
package com.example.randomizer

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.SeekBar
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.VideoView
import java.util.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val rollButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.rollButton)
        val resultsTextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.resultsTextView)
        val seekBar = findViewById<SeekBar>(R.id.seekBar)
        seekBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)
        rollButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)
        resultsTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)

        rollButton.setOnClickListener {
            val rand = Random().nextInt(seekBar.progress)
            resultsTextView.text = rand.toString()
            if rand == 9)

        }    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `if else` to toggle view visibility

```
fun View.toggleVisibility() {
    if (this.isVisible()) {
        this.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
    } else {
        this.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }
}
```

then call this function

```
seekBar.toggleVisibility()
```

Comment: The compiler doesn't know what isVisible() is (unresolved reference isVisible)

Answer (score 0):

```
val rollButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.rollButton)
val resultsTextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.resultsTextView)
val seekBar = findViewById<SeekBar>(R.id.seekBar)

seekBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)
rollButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)
resultsTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)
```

by the way you dont need to do fineViewById in kotlin, you can import them directly with synthetics.

```
fun hideViews() {
    rollButton.visibility = View.GONE
    ...
    ...
}
fun showViews() {
    rollButton.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    ...
    ...
}
```